# Unable to install Arduino

Tags: 10.04, hardware, java

At the moment, I try to install Arduino on my Ubuntu 10.04 (32 Bit) computer.
I downloaded the latest release at http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software, cd'ed to the directory and unziped the package.
When I try to run ./arduino , I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:112)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:231)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is my java -version output:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.5) (6b20-1.9.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestions on this? I try to install arduino without the 'arduino' package.

I tried to install it with apt-get (`sudo apt-get install arduino`).

When I try to start arduino (using `arduino` command) will cause following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Preferences.load(Preferences.java:553)
    at processing.app.Preferences.load(Preferences.java:549)
    at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:142)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:188)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:231)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(PApplet.java:224)
    ... 4 more
```

**Update:**
I saw that I installed several versions of jre (sun and open). So I uninstalled the open jre.

Now, when calling `arduino` I get a new error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at processing.app.Editor.populateSerialMenu(Editor.java:965)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:717)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:502)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:194)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:698)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:663)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:578)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:318)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:207)
```

Comment: You don't say why you don't want to use a package?

Comment: Also the exception relates to AWT - are you running from a Windows environment or a shell?

Comment: I tried to run it from Ubuntu 10.04 (Gnome) GUI and Shell. (GUI will do nothing and Shell throws the error)

Comment: If you found an answer, you should write it as an answer and then accept it. That's okay, as no-one else answered it yet. And that's better, because then this is not unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by copying `librxtxParallel.so` and `librxtxSerial.so` to `/usr/lib/` and the details on this post: http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1238062036/all

Answer (score 1):

By default, the java version used in Ubuntu (and this is still true in 11.10) is the OpenJDK. You can check which version of java is being used with

```
java -version
```

at the command line. There are two packages for OpenJDK in Ubuntu, `openjdk-6-jre` and `openjdk-6-jre-headless`. The headless version is intended for computers with no GUI. You have the headless version installed, causing this error when the arduino program tries to create GUI elements.

To resolve this problem, install the non-headless version. It will take over from the headless version, and the arduino IDE will start.

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

When you installed arduino from the repositories this dependency ought to have been taken care of for you. I have raised a bug for this ([Bug entry](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arduino/+bug/1029753))

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with JDK7 installed. I successfully switched back to my JDK6 with this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem after installing arduino using apt-get as detailed at http://playground.arduino.cc//Linux/Ubuntu

I found the solution was switching my JDK runtime from 7 to 6 using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been moved but can't be found at StackOverflow. Anyway, for others to know, a possible solution (worked for me) is to add

> -Djava.awt.headless=true

as option in java invocation of Arduino script.

Hope it helps